# Active Admin - refresh second drop down based on first drop down, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, drop-down-menu, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin Gem on Ruby on Rails. I have a form in which i have selected category and sub category and then accordingly i have to fill the data. So i created two tables in sqlite added in active admin resouce.

Every thing is working fine but the drop down of sub category is not getting filtered based on the category choosen.

I am new to Ruby and RoR too. I don't know how to refresh dropdown of the subcategory after selecting category.

I know i can do it from AJAX and javascript but i dont know where to code for that?

Also, is there any specific filter avaliable in Active Admin which will make it happen without ajax or javascript.

Any ideas or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Comment: would you mind to accept the answer if you agree with it? thanx

Answer (score 21):

i don't know if there is any specific filter avaliable in Active Admin, but i solved it in this 3-steps way (assuming category - is a house, subcategory - is a flat):

#### 1-st step: define helper containing ajax request

(of course, you have to predefine `path` in routes.rb)

```
#application_helper.rb
def remote_request(type, path, params={}, target_tag_id)
  "$.#{type}('#{path}',
             {#{params.collect { |p| "#{p[0]}: #{p[1]}" }.join(", ")}},
             function(data) {$('##{target_tag_id}').html(data);}
   );"
end
```

#### 2-nd step: add this method for `:onchange` action

```
#admin/inhabitants.rb (DSL with formtastic)

form do |f|
  f.inputs do
  #...
    f.input :house, :input_html => {
        :onchange => remote_request(:post, :change_flats, {:house_id=>"$('#house_id').val()"}, :flat_id)
    }
    f.input :flat
  #...
  end
end
```

#### 3-rd step: render result of filtering

(you can render partial instead of `:text`, I decided leave it in one activeadmin resource file )

```
controller do
  def change_flats
    @flats = House.find_by_id(params[:house_id]).try(:flats)
    render :text=>view_context.options_from_collection_for_select(@flats, :id, :flat_number)
  end
end
```

Comment: @okliv I am a newbie : could you be more explicit on how to define the path on routes.rb ? thanks, i've been struggling with this for hours and your post seems to meet my needs!

Comment: more than a year gone i don't remember exactly how it was but it has to be something like `post '/change_flats' =>'houses#change_flats'` - route to change_flats method in `houses_controller.rb` .. or you could define AA custom action http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html on resource or collection depending your custom case. if you ask SO question and point me to it - i will try to help directly with this in your case

Comment: @okliv thanks a lot. I will try it. I added a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034892/active-admin-refresh-second-drop-down-based-on-choice-on-first-drop-down-rails: what surprizes me is that i don't use formtastic :as =>:select  nor Collection in order to get the 2 drop down populated by the inputs i created.

Comment: @okliv can you please hv a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187354/active-admin-populate-one-of-the-second-drop-down-after-first

Comment: On doing so, i am having a problem, `{:house_id=>"$('#house_id').val()"}` the house_id gets passed as it is `$('#house_id').val()"` instead of the value being fetched and passed..

Comment: Reading this in 2023 and it's still the way to go! I used this in my teaching website in order to give an example of the syntax teachers should use to create a certain kind of exercise - depending on the chose exercise type.

Answer (score 14):

I accomplished this as any non-rails developer working on a rails project would - quick and dirty. Here's how:

```
#...
f.input :user, :input_html => {
  :onchange => "
    var user = $(this).val();

    $('#order_location_id').val(0).find('option').each(function(){
      var $option = $(this),
        isCorrectUser = ($option.attr('data-user') === user);  

        $option.prop('disabled',!isCorrectUser);
    });
  "
}
f.input :location, collection: Location.all.map{ |loc|
  [loc.name,loc.id, {"data-user" => loc.user_id}]
}
#...
```

No AJAX required. Note that this does not remove the unwanted options, it just disables them (sufficient for my scenario). This could easily be made modular with a helper, but I really only needed the functionality once.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else wrestling with the same problem, look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised)

I faced the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447164/activeadmin-formtastic-dynamic-select/17671681#17671681)

here's how I implemented multiple dynamic select menus in activeadmin:

**config/initializers/active_admin.rb**

```
  config.register_javascript 'exam_registrations.js.coffee'
```

**app/admin/exam_registrations.rb**

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Exam Registration Details" do
      f.input :user_id, :label => 'Teacher', :as => :select, :collection => User.where(:admin => 'false', :active => true).order(:name), :include_blank => true
      f.input :student_id, :hint => 'Students grouped by teacher names', :as => :select, :collection => option_groups_from_collection_for_select(User.where(:admin => false, :active => true).order(:name), :students, :name, :id, :name)
      f.input :lesson_id, :hint => 'Lessons grouped by student names', :as => :select, :collection => option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Student.where(:active => true).order(:name), :lessons, :name, :id, :name)
    end
    f.buttons
  end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/exam_registrations.js.coffee**

```
#first menu    
jQuery ->
      $('#exam_registration_student_id').parent().hide()
      students = $('#exam_registration_student_id').html()
      $('#exam_registration_user_id').change ->
        user = $('#exam_registration_user_id :selected').text()
        escaped_user = user.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
        options = $(students).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_user}']").html()
        if options
          $('#exam_registration_student_id').html(options)
          $('#exam_registration_student_id').parent().show()
        else
          $('#exam_registration_student_id').empty()
          $('#exam_registration_lesson_id').empty()

# second menu
  $('#exam_registration_lesson_id').parent().hide()
  lessons = $('#exam_registration_lesson_id').html()
  $('#exam_registration_student_id').click ->
    student = $('#exam_registration_student_id :selected').text()
    escaped_student = student.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(lessons).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_student}']").html()
    if options
      $('#exam_registration_lesson_id').html(options)
      $('#exam_registration_lesson_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#exam_registration_lesson_id').empty()
```

restart the server and the menus work!

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible with this gem https://github.com/holyketzer/activeadmin-ajax_filter, use in you form code like this:

```rb
f.input :category_id, as: :select # ...
f.input :subcategory_id, as: :ajax_select, data: { 
  ajax_search_fields: [:category_id], 
  search_fields: [:subcategory_atrribute], 
  url: '/admin/subcategories/filter' 
}
```

And in you subcategory resource page:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Subcategory do
  include ActiveAdmin::AjaxFilter
  # ...
end
```

don't forget to include assets

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `activeadmin_addons` gem [Nested Select](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_nested_select.md)

Answer (score 0):

[dependent-select](https://github.com/abhidsm/dependent-select) could be also a good option