# updating content using AJAX queries in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

beginner in rails/ajax/jquery, so unsure of how to implement. basically, i have a planner page where filtered results from my database is displayed (results are filtered by multiple parameters).

I have a bunch of toggles and dropdowns, all of which are in the same form and have values that need to be passed to the database in order to filter the results.

i want to query the database when any of these toggles/dropdowns are changed, and update the result listing with ajax.

results, toggles are in planner/index
filtering is done in Planner_controller, which calls different models restaurant.rb and activities.rb

{

```
class PlannerController < ApplicationController
def index
puts "these are params"
#Restaurant.create params[:restaurant]
#params[:restaurant]
b,g,a,l,t,loc = "b2", "g2", "a2", "l2", "t2", "newyork"
if(params[:budget] != nil)
  b= params[:budget]
end
if(params[:size] != nil)
  g=params[:size]
end
if(params[:age] != nil)
  a= params[:age]
end
if(params[:activity] != nil)
  l= params[:activity]
end
if(params[:tourist] != nil)
  t= params[:tourist]
end
if(params[:city] != nil)
    loc = params[:city]
end    

@lrestaurants = Restaurant.lsearching(b,g,a,l,t,loc)
@drestaurants = Restaurant.dsearching(b,g,a,l,t,loc)
@activities = Activity.searching(b,g,a,l,t,loc)
activitieslist = @activities
drestlist = @drestaurants 
lrestlist = @lrestaurants 
end
```

}

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i gave earlier almost the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603188/868273)

the only difference is you need to render erb form (i guess) but in my example - it is ActiveAdmin DSL

to render partial instead of inline text you need to complete two additional steps

change render method according to this

```
 def change_flats
   @flats = House.find_by_id(params[:house_id]).try(:flats)

   respond_to do |format|
     format.js(render :layout=>false)
   end
 end
```

and create partial `change_flats.js.erb` with JS you need to replace a part of your current page

```
#change_flats.js.erb

$("#block_id").html("<%= render 'partial_with_necessary_html_here' %>")
```

Comment: i guess its similar, but my results of my query is a list of activities/restaurants. i dont want to show it in a dropdown, rather, i want to update my display with x amount of entries taken from this list. the list should change after each query.

Comment: where should the change_flats.js.erb go ? and would my partial be _planner ? or would it be _update (the method i called)

Comment: in my example the name of partial is 'change_flats' - because this name has the method rendered JS in controller... if you have controller, i don't know, 'cities' and need on city page update list of restaurants, than you have to create action 'change_restaurants' in cities_controller (like change_flats in houses_controller in my case)... update action, according to CRUD, uses to update db not pages