# Active Admin, populate one of the second drop down after first

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using a word to category mapping. A word can be mapped to a category or a type. In database, I have words table, categories table, types table and a join mappings called word_categories which contains the word_id, cat_type (having value either category or type), cat_id (if the cat_type is category the cat_id corresponds to categories table, or if the cat_type is type the cat_id corresponds to the type table).

In active admin keyword_categories.rb i have

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    if f.object.new_record?
      f.input :word, as: :select, collection: Word.unmapped.pluck(:word)
      f.input :cat_type, as: :select, :collection => ["Type", "Category"]
      if true #here i have to give some logic to select on the basis of the value selected in the first drop down
        f.input :cat_id, as: :select, :collection => Type.pluck(:name)
      else 
        f.input :cat_id, as: :select, :collection => Category.pluck(:name)
      end
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

I followed [SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447164/activeadmin-formtastic-dynamic-select?lq=1), but i dont understand, how do i return value from the controller to the active admin rb file

I am a newbie to jquery

Answer (score 0):

The ERB code that's in the view *only* gets run when the page is first loaded. You can't use it to build conditionals based on the live value of something in the page.

Long story short, the whole `if` block needs to go into your javascript. It'll look *something* like:

```
<script>
  if($("object_cat_type").value() === "Category") {
    $("object_cat_id").innerHTML("<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Category.pluck(:name)) %>");
  } else if($("object_cat_type").value() === "Type") {
    $("object_cat_id").innerHTML("<%= options_from_collection_for_select(Type.pluck(:name)) %>");
  }
</script>
```

My jQuery is also a little rusty, though, so double check stuff against the documentation, especially that `innerHTML` function.