# Active Admin nested select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have Active Admin gem for my ruby on rails project. What I would like to do is create a product and have 2 select boxes (1-Category, 2-Department) in that form where the second one changes it's content based on the first one. After countless hours of searching I still can't get this to work.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category, dependent: :destroy, counter_cache: true
has_one :department, through: :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :department, counter_cache: true
has_many :products
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The reason I would like to do this is because some departments might have the same category name that would be confusing and would add the product to the wrong department.

I have tried [question 9579402](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579402/active-admin-refresh-second-drop-down-based-on-first-drop-down-ruby-on-rails) but how I understand his question is that he had only 2 models and he was creating sub-category from selected category

Heres a familiar thing, but he uses a get ajax request [Git/Dglgmut/6328501](https://gist.github.com/Dglgmut/6328501)

Trying [question 9579402](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579402/active-admin-refresh-second-drop-down-based-on-first-drop-down-ruby-on-rails) get me error:

```
Started POST "/admin/products/change_categories" for ::1 at 2016-03-30 14:51:09 +0300
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST]    "/admin/products/change_categories"):
```

This is what I have in routes.rb

```
routes.rb = post 'change_categories'        =>'products#change_categories'  
http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes = change_categories_path    POST    /change_categories(.:format)    products#change_categories
```

I guess this is because I can use Member Actions for Active admin, so I tried it

```
member_action :change_categories, :method => :get do
  @categories = Department.find_by_id(params[:department_id]).try(:categories)
  render :text=>view_context.options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :category_number)
end
```

But got the same error as before. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:
Im a beginner at this, but if im correct, change_categories should be in categories controller, because it's searching for that method in product controller,

```
POST "/admin/products/change_categories"
```

So I added categories resource to Active Admin and added that method to categories controller, but is there now a way to use that controller? Something like:

```
f.input :department, :input_html => { :onchange => remote_request(controller => "categories", :post, :change_categories, {:department_id=>"$('#department_id').val()"}, :category_id) }
```

Comment: i think adding `get "/admin/products/change_categories" => "products#change_categories"` will do your job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after countless hours I have managed to get this to work. I think problem was in old versions or difference between models from where I took the code. So in Active Admin instead of member_action I used collection_action that makes more sense in routing, because 
member_action creates route /admin/products/:id/change_categories(.:format)
that interferes with show action and uses it instead of change_categories action.

So heres collection_action:

```
collection_action :change_categories, :method => :get do
@categories = Category.where("department_id = ?", Department.find(params[:product_department_id]))
render :text => view_context.options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :name)
end
```

This generates correct route admin/products/change_categories where I can now pass params[:product_departmemnt_id] which is selected id from select box.

This is where it gets Id from:

```
f.input :description
    f.input :department, prompt: "Select department", :input_html => {
    onchange: remote_get("change_categories", 'product_department_id', :product_category_id)
}
    f.input :category
```

Tip for some ajax beginners, make sure to check source code of webpage to see if you are using the right id or class or whatever, this has caused headaches for me.

Next thing you want to add is helper method, there are two ways to do this, either in application_helper.rb or in app/helpers. If you add it to appication_helper.rb you have to include it to config/initializers/active_admin.rb initializer:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  ....
  some config
  ....
end

module ActiveAdmin::ViewHelpers
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

But this then has access to all of its helper methods which I don't think is needed or might/might not slow down it, so I created new folder in app/helpers called "active_admin" and created a file "form_helper.rb" where is this code from [Dglgmut/6328501 git](https://gist.github.com/Dglgmut/6328501)

```
def remote_get(path, member,target_tag_id)
 "$.get('#{path}/?#{member}=' + $('##{member}').val(),
  function(data) {$('##{target_tag_id}').html(data);}
 );"
end
```

Don't know much about js, but I assume this makes get request to admin/products/change_categories/?product_department_id=1 and the rest happens in helper method. If anyone stumbles upon this, I hope this helps you and has information you need. I also suggest you so called "rubber duck" debugging, no jokes, this helps sometimes.

Comment: PS: Active admin needs server restart after adding or editing(i think) helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your member_action method is "get" and you are posting to the controller. Change from "POST" to do a Get request should solve the problem.

Comment: This is what it spit out now:   Started GET "/admin/products/change_categories" for ::1 at 2016-03-30 15:28:56 +0300
Processing by Admin::ProductsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"change_categories"}
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=change_categories):

Comment: remove post 'change_categories' from routes.rb. member_action will add active_admin routes. add ActiveAdmin.routes(self) near the bottom of routes.rb if its not there.

Comment: paste your `routes.rb` file to justpaste and share the link.

Comment: remove line no 18.

Comment: Well, removing post 'change_categories' from routes.rb did what it had to do as you said, but the error, the one in comments is still there

Comment: Is it exactly the same?

Comment: Yea, the problem seems to be that on change it sends Parameters: {"id"=>"change_categories"}, but it should send corresponding department id instead and it searched in Product database instead of Categories. Heres the code http://pastebin.com/qwyHQBA2

Comment: Ok, so I checked source code on chrome and it turns out select box id was named differently :get, :change_categories, {:department_id=>"$('#product_department_id').val()"} instead of #department_id, so thats good, but its still the same error except that one right param

Comment: Ok now the problem seems to be with the routes. There is a route admin/products/:id is matching the request. Can you link the output of bundle exec rake routes | grep products? Also i see member_action as well as change_categories in controller? Any reason for that?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iGwtsB3r Yes, there seems to be a problem with route /admin/products/:id/change_categories(.:format) because console output is: /admin/products/change_categories?department_id=1 but it should be with a slash "/" after change_categories, right?

Comment: Ok, it seems that member_action creates wrong route  /admin/products/:id/update_categories as red in their documentation, so I tried collection_action instead and it now generates admin/products/update_categories where it now should pass params(department_id) console also gets better output http://pastebin.com/tKfDctLG